# Does printf() invoke the short term scheduler to schedule another process in ready queue?

Tags: io, operating-system, scheduler, context-switch

When a process tries to output to the console (using printf) , does it come under I/O event where it will be sent to the waiting queue and so, the short term scheduler comes into action and selects another process to take the cpu time 
Does context switch occur here, at the console output event ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it may do, yes, if the I/O stream is locked by another thread that is performing output.

Not use what you mean by 'short term scheduler'.  The console stream will probably be protected by a mutex and gets locked/unlocked by threads in the 'usual' way when they request I/O.

Comment: The short-term scheduler (also known as the CPU scheduler) decides which of the ready, in-memory processes are to be executed (allocated a CPU) after a clock interrupt, an I/O interrupt, an operating system call or another form of signal

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do manual synchronization. You can not make the assumption that it is thread safe.
If you want, separate threads don't access the stream at the same time, you need to  wrap output with a mutex.